# C# Winforms how can I test for SQL connection when using EF6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 as part of my C# Winforms application.  My underlying database is SQL Server Express 2014.

I'm trying to test if the DB is there by doing this:

```
    MyEntity me = new MyEntity()

    // Try and open the connection, if unable to, show an error message and exit
    try
    {
        me.Database.Connection.Open();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to database!\n\nError message:\n" + ex.Message, "Unable to connect to Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

I currently have this in the 'Load' event of my form, but I understand this doesn't work because the message pumps haven't started yet.

My question is, what is the earliest I can exit (gracefully) if the DB isn't running?

Comment: Putting it in the `Shown()` event doesn't work either.

Comment: You mean you don't see the MessageBox because you exit your application?

Comment: Sorry, no, I mean I see the messagebox, but execution of my program continues rather than exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to show a message box then I'd do it just before your main form is created:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    // Test database connection...
    if noConnection
    {
        return;
    }

    // Start the application.
    Application.Run(new Form1());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

When catching an exception and showing a MessageBox, you should at least leave some time to be able to read the message.

Using the following code will stop the application from closing until you hit "OK".

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Error message:\n" + ex.Message, "Unable to connect to database!",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.OK)
{
     Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I see the message box, but execution of my program continues past the `Application.Exit()` call.

Comment: You probably haven't run the application yet, you could try exiting the environment although this is more for console applications. `System.Environment.Exit(0);` there are different exit codes you could use just have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(VS.85).aspx)